# incrementing by 1 in vb10 connected to sql edited

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

i want to have an student id with last 2 digits of the year and a string of -001 example 13-001 and read the last value in the table example 13-002 is the last value in the table how it can becomes 13-003 when the forms load. i have a value on table 13-001 and i had been try this code but it gives me 14 instead 13-002

```
 Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand
    con.Open()
    With Cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student ORDER BY Student_no DESC"
    End With
    dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then
        lblstudno.Text = Val(dr.Item(0)) + 1

    End If

    con.Close()
```

thanks hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO
    students
( student_id ) VALUES
(
    CAST( ( YEAR( GETDATE() ) % 100 ) + 1 AS varchar(2) ) + '-' + 
    CAST( 
           SELECT TOP 1
               CAST( RIGHT( student_id, 3 ) AS int ) + 1
           FROM
               students
           ORDER BY
               student_id DESC

    AS varchar(3) )
)
```

Note that this will fail if you reach 999 students. There is also a potential race condition unless you do a lock of some kind on the table (see transaction isolation).

My post also demonstrates why `IDENTITY` keys are generally a good idea instead of rolling your own (assuming you want to use this system as your primary key).